# Getting properites of static class in static function?

Tags: php, function, static

I just wanna get return class properties in not instantiated class use. There is no way to instance this class? Please tell me...!
My example is below↓↓

```
  <?php
    class MyTest {
        public static $test1 = 'a';
        
        public static $test2 = 'b';
        
        public static function getProperties() {
            //how to code here...?
        }
    }
    //plz return $test1, $test2
    MyTest::getProperties();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `self::` to access static properties:

```php
public static function getProperties() {
    return [self::$test1, self::$test2];
}
```

Comment: @HirokiTakekuma If you find my answer to be correct and helpful, please mark it as correct and upvote it. Welcome to Stack Overflow